# How can I publish site from command line with some publish profile?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Something like

`msbuild /t:publish [use PublishProfileName] someproject.csproj`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:Configuration=Release;_PackageTempDir=C:\temp\somelocation;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

See [MSBuild 2010 - how to publish web app to a specific location (nant)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928595/msbuild-2010-how-to-publish-web-app-to-a-specific-location-nant)

For Visual Studio 2012 you can use

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Production;Password=foo
```

See [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Command Line Deployment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)

Comment: My web.config ends up like this after running that msbuild command:

 
<connectionStrings> <add name="principal" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_principal-Web.config Connection String_0)" providerName= ..

Comment: @Jhonny You need AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings parameter, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative solution for achieving Pavel's solution but using MsBuild target in a MsBuild file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build"  
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
        <OutputDirectory>$(DeploymentProject)\bin\$(Configuration)</OutputDirectory>
        <OutputPath>C:\Inetpub\wwwroot</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="build">
        <MSBuild 
        Projects="Your Solution File.sln"
        Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;_PackageTempDir=$(OutputPath);AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false"
        >
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>
</Project>
```