# What happen when I use Publish Web command from VS 2012 with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

What exactly happen when I use Publish Web command inside Visual Studio 2012 for ASP MVC project?

How can I activate the same command from command line?

Answer (score 1):

It just call specific target to execute via MSBuild engine. That target could call MSDeploy tool to perform actual deployment (or could not, depending on profile settings)

Check [this questions answer for the second part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412900/how-can-i-publish-site-from-command-line-with-some-publish-profile)

Comment: My question is which specific target is execute and in which .target file is it define? I found that the web deployment targets are defined in MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets but I found only Package target and not Deploy target in there.

Comment: Looks like I've found the answer and it is **MSDeployPublish** inside Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets

Comment: For vs2012 MSDeployPublish target executed, for VS2010 - PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak - FYI, You can make VS2012's publishing available to VS2010 by installing the Azure SDK Tools for VS 2010. It will create a new "v10.5" Publishing.targets and connect it up to WebApplication.targets so no changes are required per project.

Comment: @RichardSzalay Thanks for hint. But I never heard that an AzureSDK tools makes changes to the WebPublishing.targets file. Sounds scary cause imo they should be independent from eachother

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak - It modifies WebApplication.targets to import 10.5\Web.Publishing.targets rather than the default 10.0\Web.Publishing.targets, bringing functional parity with the 2012 (11.0) target files.