# How to automate Web Deploy of a specific Publish Profile with an MSBuild script?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, webdeploy

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution, which contains three web projects. Each of them has a web deploy publish profile, which creates a package in a specific directory. The solution itself also has a special Deployment configuration.

Using msbuild, building the solution in a Deployment configuration is easy, but how can I publish the 3 web projects using a specific profile using an msbuild build **script/task (rather than invoking command lines)**?

Answer (score 12):

I think you can try the following:

```
msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=MyProfile
```

as pointed by Steve, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664145/1990682) post by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi  seems to address your requirement publish from an msbuild in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Are all three published profiles named the same way? If so, could you just add

`/p:PublishProfile=MyProfile` to the msbuild command?

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890289/how-do-i-configure-msbuild-to-use-a-saved-publishprofile-for-webdeploy) for more info

Comment: My question is about publishing from an msbuild script. I assumed there is an msbuild task that can be used, but so far the documentation is very scarce.

Comment: The documentation is scarce. Have you tried something like this script, though?

`msbuild MySolution.sln /t:build /p:PublishProfile=MyProfile`