# Why won't my Visual Studio 2012 publish correctly using msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild, microsoft-web-deploy

We use Jenkins and msbuild to compile and package our software.

We've upgraded to Visual Studio 2012, which greatly improves the command line publishing functionality.

According to this: [How do I configure MSBuild to use a saved publishProfile for WebDeploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890289/how-do-i-configure-msbuild-to-use-a-saved-publishprofile-for-webdeploy)

I should be able to create the profile (I have, it working in VS2012 and deploys to C:\Built\PojectName) and in the jenkins job fire it off with:

```
msbuild myproj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Jenkins$Configuration.pubxml
```

Where `$Configuration` is `Debug`.

The build runs and finishes with "SUCCESS".

However, there is no `Built` folder created, there is a `.zip` file inside `obj\debug`

This is not what it's configured to do:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Built\blahblah</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Further to that, if I *deliberately* munge the profile name to, say, `NoSuchFile.pubxml`, it *still* completes with success.

On the server we have Jenkins, .net 4.5, a recent Windows SDK and MS Web Deploy 2.0 installed.

Why is `msbuild` not picking up my publish profile?

Comment: I'm having the same problem where when I deploy through Visual Studio everything I need goes to the correct location, however when I build through MSBUILD the files are safed to another location.