# TFS Build definition started to deploy just the source code instead of binaries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I am using a TFS build definition using Continuous Integration and immediately deploy the binaries to an IIS site.

(Actually, I "was")

I have implemented the solution [Team Build: Publish locally using MSDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041836/team-build-publish-locally-using-msdeploy). It run pretty cool.

After a while, I have modified something somewhere and now **the build definition deploys just the source code but no binaries at all**. If I check the "drops" folder, "_PublishedWebsites" is correctly created.

How can I have my output destination cover again binaries rather than source codes?