# Deployment using MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

Is there anyway to customise TFS2012 interface to run MSDeploy commands via TFS intranet access, instead of running command prompts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean as [part of your build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041836/team-build-publish-locally-using-msdeploy) or [using the ms deploy ui on your machine](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/09/HowToCreateWebDeployPackagesInVisualStudio2012.aspx), or if you mean from web access then you can use [tfs deployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not such an extension endpoint in TF Web Access 2012. The only way to extend Web Access is work item types today (which only works for on-premise version).