# Publish from TFS 2013 to WebSite IIS : Failed with no error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5

At my company, we have received Team Foundation Server 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 to manage our code and deployment.

I'm trying to make it work but I can't figure out what I miss.

So here is the scenario :
I have a Web Application with no DB for the moment.
It's added to TFS and I have checked in everything.
There is a Build Controller on TFS.

On the Web Server, Web Deploy is installed and Management Services is there and allow remote management. The services are running. I have create a website but the folder with the source is empty for now.

My objective is to build on TFS and deploy from there in one single operation with the build definition.

Here is my problem, the build is working fine and everything is put in the drop folder. But it deploy nothing on the webserver and It raised no error on the build.

I tryied two techniques for the MSBuild arguments:

1) I create a publish profile in VS, when I publish from there it works but with this argument it does nothing:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=PublishIGU
```

2) I use this argument :

> /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
>   /p:MSDeployServiceURL=https://{serverWeb}:8172/msdeploy.axd 
>   /p:DeployIISAppPath=IGUDEV /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
>   /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:UserName=DOMAIN\user
>   /p:Password=XXXXX

And... it still does nothing.

I read a lot on the internet and follow tutorials but I can't figure this out.
Like I don't have any error message I don't know where to start.

Thank you if you see something that could help me.

Comment: Take a look at the msbuild log file to see what it shows.

Comment: I did and I  didn't found anything. Here is a log.  http://pastebin.com/r9xF35qs

Comment: I took a look at your log. I don't see msdeploy being called. I don't know why from just a quick look, but I'd suggest taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041836/team-build-publish-locally-using-msdeploy and http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.ca/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html. Sayed and Vishal were on the msdeploy team, so I hope the answer may be in there.