# MsBuild: Generate binaries instead of zip file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to build a solution and have the generated artifacts (binaries) in a folder rather than having them packaged in a zip file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found working was to simply providing *OutputPath*:

```
msbuild.exe <solution.sln> /p:OutputPath="<target_directory>"
```

Just be careful the *targe_directory* shouldn't end with `\` .

Answer (score 1):

You can try publishing them to a file system from visual studio

[image]

or you if you want to use the console you can try using this

[Using MSBuild, how do I build an MVC4 solution from the command line (applying Web.config transformations in the process) and output to a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273551/using-msbuild-how-do-i-build-an-mvc4-solution-from-the-command-line-applying-w)