# upgraded from VS2010 to VS2013 now I cannot publish

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msdeploy

I can publish without issues in Visual Studio 2010 but when I attempt to publish with Visual Studio 2013 I am getting this message:

> The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project.    \Source2\Web Projects\SubService\subservice\subservice.csproj   0   0   subservice

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to resolve this? It's happening with 2 different projects.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

after 4 hours I found a post not directly related to this but I took a blind shot and it worked:

Install from "Web Platform Installer" I installed the "Windows Azure SDK for .Net (VS 2013)" and that worked !

Answer (score 24):

For what its worth;

I had the same issue. Fresly installed Windows 8.1 machine, only installed Visual Studio 2013 (+update1) + Azure SDK's . Create new Web Api Project **boom** build error -

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

note the v10.0. This is the default fallback when no MSBuild parameter "VisualStudioVersion" has been set. [Prior to VS2012 the paths to the target files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026754/msbuild-deploy-failing-after-upgrade-to-net-4-5) were hardcoded. Other solutions for this bugs say [to remove the following from your csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not) which is added for backward compatibility:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But removing this fixes your builds but breaks the publish feature with the original posters error:

> The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project

Note: I have all Azure related SDK parts installed from the web platform installer.

I have resorted to re-adding the above XML part to my csproj file but changing the *10.0* part to *12.0* (=vs2013)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This might break backward compatibility but finally made my Visual Studio 2013 compile the code & made the publish feature work again.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than +1 for this.

Comment: YES!! I had the exact same issue with upgrading to VS2013 and making these changes solved the prob. Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install visual studio on build server, you can use this NuGet package with portable version of the targets: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets and modify your csproj file to include it like this:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.12.0.1\tools\VSToolsPath\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Solution originally posted here: [Where is MsDeployPublish located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295854/where-is-msdeploypublish-located) 
(in my case it was already MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.**14.0.0**).