# Web Deploy in Visual Studio 2013 - untrusted certificate error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have a C# MVC project in Visual Studio Express 2013. I'm using the Publish Web option and Web Deploy as the method.

After a bunch of work to get Web Deploy setup on the target machine, I finally got a valid connection:

Screenshot here (since I don't have the reputation to add the image to the post): http://screencast.com/t/Q5IccavcB1

However, when I actually publish, I get this error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("myServerName.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.

The help information I find is almost exclusively for VS 2010, which isn't very helpful here. I finally tried adjusting my .pubxml file by directly adding AllowUntrustedCertificate = True in the PropertyGroup, but that has no effect.

Screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas? I'm out of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that an artifact left over from trying to get an MSBuild for TeamCity working was the cause of the problem.

[upgraded from VS2010 to VS2013 now I cannot publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003559/upgraded-from-vs2010-to-vs2013-now-i-cannot-publish)

I added back in the PropertyGroup that I removed yesterday, and I was able to publish.

Answer (score 0):

adding /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true argument in msbuild.exe resolve my problem
[How can resolve Untrusted certificates Error ?( TFS2013 Build and deploy to IIS )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842222/how-can-resolve-untrusted-certificates-error-tfs2013-build-and-deploy-to-iis/41054717#41054717)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question then [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If the question is not a duplicate then tailor the answer to this specific question.