# How can resolve Untrusted certificates Error ?( TFS2013 Build and deploy to IIS )

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, webdeploy

I crate a build definition on tfs2013.when I queue my builddefinition I get an error about Untrusted certificates.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4270): Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("developertest") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"), but could not verify the server’s certificate. If you trust the server, connect again and allow untrusted certificates.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED.

I check help link and it has 3 way to resolve it

- From the msdeploy.exe command line, you can do this by passing the -allowUntrusted flag.
- From the Visual Studio 2010 publish UI, you can check "Allow untrusted"
- From a Visual Studio 2010 deployment package (e.g. MyApp.deploy.cmd), you can pass the -allowUntrusted flag

For first and third way I dont know  how do it 
In second way   I cant find Allow untrusted in vs2013 publish dialog

Comment: Or you can trust the server certificate by adding it to your Windows truststore. On what port do you connect to the target server ? What protocol is it (https, ldaps...) ?

Comment: @Iansus my deploy url is  https://developertest:8172/msdeploy.axd

Comment: Navigate to this address using your browser and HTTPS. Then grab the certificate (using the lock icon) and save it on your computer. Then open it, click on "install certificate", choose " root CA" location, and that should work.

Comment: @Iansus I did it.but my problem not solved

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I add /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true to MsBuild arguments.and it's resolved

Comment: You can also use  -allowUntrusted

Comment: And where do we do that at?

Comment: @tnk479 in MsBuild argument

Answer (score 2):

Thanks M.Azad, It resolved my problem. 
I was trying to set these configurations in .pubxml file True
False 
but that was not resolving the issue, but adding `/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true` arugment in msbuild.bat file resolved.

Complete argument list to msbuild.exe

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe %ProjectPath%   /fl /flp:logfile=%LogPath% /T:Build  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
>   /p:PublishProfile=%ProfilePath% /p:PublishDir="C:\wwroot" **/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true** /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

Answer (score 0):

Publish to a server using an untrusted certificate

```
Add the <AllowUntrustedCertificate> property with a value of True to the publish profile: C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\xxxx\xxxx\Properties\PublishProfiles\IISProfile.pubxml
```

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#publish-to-a-server-using-an-untrusted-certificate