# The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project on VS 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, msdeploy, web-publishing

> [The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634039/the-target-msdeploypublish-does-not-exist-in-the-project)
>
> I see people refer to this link as it would give the solution to my
>   problem. I read the complete thread and tried every single idea given
>   there. Nothing worked. I also use VS 2015 Community and not VS 2013.

I am trying to publish a Web API through VS 2015 Community. I have done it before, but this time it seems to not be working.

I got the publish settings from IIS on the server and the validation on the connection works fine.

When I do the publish I get this error:

> The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project

I tried several things, but the most mentioned one is (re)installing the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` NuGet Package and check the CSPROJ file for these two lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You already guessed that this isn't working in my case (otherwise I wouldn't post here).

The first thing I notice is the version 10.0. I backtracked the path and there isn't a version 10.0 on my disk. Only 12, 14 and 15. 14 seems to have the targets, so I changed the version to 14... Same error.

I tried to install several packages, checked the CSPROJ file again and nothing seems to happen. Same error over and over again (getting a bit frustrated here... )

Does anyone have another solution for this?

*** UPDATE ***

It seems to work on other projects. It looks like something is wrong with this particular project.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

I set up a FTP connection to the host, as I was trying something else. I tried to publish with the FTP, but gave almost the same error:

> The target "GatherAllFilesToPublish" does not exist in the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The target "MSDeployPublish" does not exist in the project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634039/the-target-msdeploypublish-does-not-exist-in-the-project)

Comment: Whilst the second answer is correct, the issue is not fixed unless you explicitly restart the VS.NET as 2013/2015 cache the targets on startup meaning that you can follow all the steps but still get the same error, as to the install as Administrator this was not required. **Edit: 1** If this is not the answer please could you actually provide the solution!
As it has worked for me, but moving branches causes the issue to reappear.

Comment: Wasn't the answer to my problem. Maybe to something else, I don't know

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone have another solution for this?

I have encountered this error before, I resolved by following method. Not sure if it works for you, but you can try it.

First, Install Packages(**Run VS as Administrator**)：

```
install-package MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets

install-package Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish
```

Second, Edit WebJob Project File:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note:

1. Make sure your VisualStudio is running as "**Administrator**", otherwise, the install.ps1 possibly throws an error when installing that package.
2. `<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>` Only when the condition is null, the value of VisualStudioVersion  will be set to 10.0 rather than set this value to 10.0.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I always run VS as admin. Like said in the original post: I don't see a v10.0 in my directory structure on the hard drive.

Maybe a stupid question, but where can I find the WebJob Project file?

Last: Please see also my updated original post

Answer (score 0):

If anybody gets this with newer Studios, check if you have uninstalled .NET Core 3.1 and accidentally removed the whole Web Development Workload.