# MSBUILD command not able to create artifacts

Tags: c#, msbuild, devops

Tring to build asp.net web application using MSbuild. Build getting successful but in `build_output` folder only DLLs are present. When i do publish from visual studio I get a different output which i can deploy to IIS. But MSBUILD gives different output. I want same output as publish from visual studio.

The command I am using:

`msbuild ASPWebApp.sln /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:Configuration=Release /p:outdir=.\build_output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web application builds use a different target.  Try the "/t:WebPublish" target.

```
/t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PublishUrl="c:\build\output"
```

Comment: Updated command as per your suggestion .`msbuild ASPWebApp/ASPWebApp.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl=.\output`. Getting error `The target "WebPublish" does not exist in the project`

Comment: Check out this answer [9169341](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169341/how-to-use-msbuild-msdeploypublish-to-target-local-file-system)